# How to use APA 6 with elsarticle.cls

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apa6, elsarticle

First, let me tell you that I am a total newbie in Latex.

I am trying to use APA 6 with elsarticle. As far as I get, elsarticle has natbib pre-loaded. Does anyone help me use APA with elsarticle? elsarticle has elsarticle-harv and elsarticle-num bibliography styles. How can I use a different style (APA in my case)?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it so far?