# What is the best way to use APA with elsarticle?

Tags: apa-style, elsarticle

So I am preparing a submission for an Elsevier journal. It is neccessary to use the APA style for bibliography. Now, I am currently aware of three approaches (apalike, apacite and elsevier version). However, the related results for these approaches are very discouraging.

- **apalike**: Is is clearly mentioned that this is quite an old implementation and that is should not be used for submitting to an APA journal ([What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263793/what-is-the-relationship-between-natbib-apacite-package-and-apa-document-class))
- **apacite**: It has been recommend before not to combine apacite with elsarticle ([apacite bibliography style doesn't in Elsevier latex format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269915/apacite-bibliography-style-doesnt-in-elsevier-latex-format)). It also generates a large number of errors if attempted.
- **Elsevier version of APA**: It is suggested that the model5-names should be used, but it does not exist anymore and the corresponding links are broken ([apacite bibliography style doesn't in Elsevier latex format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269915/apacite-bibliography-style-doesnt-in-elsevier-latex-format))

Currently, these .bst files are provided by Elsarticle, but it is not clear if any of those implement APA: elsarticle-harv.bst, elsarticle-num.bst and elsartice-num-names.bst.

There is also another question asking the same thing, which were never addressed:
[How to use APA 6 with elsarticle.cls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175593/how-to-use-apa-6-with-elsarticle-cls)

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote,

> **apacite**: It has been recommend before not to combine apacite with elsarticle ([apacite bibliography style doesn't in Elsevier latex format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269915/apacite-bibliography-style-doesnt-in-elsevier-latex-format)). It also generates a large number of errors if attempted.

Not true! Just load the `elsarticle` document class with the option `nonatbib`; this is explained in more detail on p. 3 of the user guide of the [elsarticle](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) bundle. Then, load the `apacite` package and the `apacite` bibliography style to obtain APA6 formatting of the bibliographic entries and the citation call-outs. Not only will you not get a "a large number of errors" from following this approach, you'll get *no errors*.

[image]

```
\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{abc:3001,
  author  = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3001,
  volume  = 1,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = "3--4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{abc:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```